# How do I interpolate color palettes in GGPlot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I find that the pre-defined palettes are great, but sometimes they don't have enough values for the number of columns that I want to visualize. I'd like to interpolate a continuous color scale from two sets of discrete colors.

Here's an example where the discrete colors don't solve the problem

```
# organize the data
tdf_winners <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-04-07/tdf_winners.csv')

wins.by.winner_name <-
  tdf_winners %>% 
  count(winner_name) %>% 
  arrange(-n) %>% 
  mutate(total_wins = n) %>% 
  select(-n)

tdf_winners <-
  tdf_winners %>% 
  filter(start_date > ymd("1913-01-01")) %>%
  left_join(wins.by.winner_name, by = "winner_name") %>% 
    mutate(winner_name_lbl = ifelse(total_wins == 1, "One Time Winner",
                                  winner_name))

# create the graphic

gg <-
    tdf_winners %>% 
    ggplot(aes(edition, time_overall, fill = winner_name_lbl)) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = 5)
```

In a perfect world, I'd be able to take the highest color and the lowest color from the palette and apply them to my ggplot.

Can I do that?

Comment: `colorRampPalette(colors)(n)` where `colors` is a vector and `n` is the number you need although you may need to use `scale_fill_manual` instead

Comment: This is great, but how can I get the hexes for the colors? For example, how would I get the hexes for colors from palettes like `wesanderson` or `yarr`?

Comment: they are stored in hexadecimal https://github.com/karthik/wesanderson/blob/master/R/colors.R